# Arduino: turn on and off ethernet server availability

Tags: webserver, arduino

I need to setup an ethernet (web) server that have to be turned on and off depending on some conditions on the Arduino UNO.

I read the docs of the `Server` class in the [`Ethernet` library](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) and it seems there is no chance to stop the server once you started, i.e. there is no `EthernetServer.begin()` counterpart.

I thought then to setup the server in the `setup` section and serve incoming connections depending on when the given condition:

```
EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(80);

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {

  if (condition) {

    EthernetClient client = server.available();
    if (client == true) {
      // serve the client...
    }

  } else {
    // do something else
  }

}
```

This indeed works, but the client is not properly rejected: it is just leaved pending. In the browser one can see the web page loading idefinitely, and if the condition turns to `true` the client will eventually be served for the request issued when the condition was `false`.

I see no methods for rejecting the request (there is no counterpart of `EthernetServer.available()`). The only thing that comes to my mind is to perform a

```
server.available().stop();
```

in the beginning of the else block. This prevent to serve requests issued while the condition was `false`, but doesn't prevent the connection between the client and the server to take place (it's like opening a connection and shut it down immediately).

How could I avoid to establish connections at all while the condition is `false`?

Comment: Self-reset using the watchdog?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here since I don't have my Arduino collection handy, but from memory and reading the reference you could try something like

```
void loop() 
{
    EthernetClient client = server.available();
    if ( !condition )
    {
        client.stop(); // break connection and do something else
    }
    else
    {
        // serve the client...
    }
}
```

Hope that may at least help you in the right direction.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you but I have already taken in account this design in the last paragraph of my question. I'd like to reject incomnig connections instead of accepting them and give zero byte responses.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just return a 404 header when you want the server disabled?

```
if(!condition)
{
     client.println("HTTP/1.1 404 OK");
     client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
     client.println("Connnection: close");
     client.println();
     client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
     client.println("<html><body>404</body></html>");
}
else
{
     // serve client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer here as it is the only post still active or that hasn't been closed regarding this topic. Despite countless researches regarding being able to switch the EthernetServer on or off at will, this is not possible. The only thing you can do is use some functions defined "public" in the classes of the Ethernet/W5100/W5200/W5500 libraries.
The features I've noticed that actually impact the reliability of the network card are:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <utility/w5100.h>
W5100.setRetransmissionTime(milliseconds);
W5100.setRetransmissionCount(number);
```

(helps to shorten waiting times in case of Wiznet W5100/W5200/W5500 network card timeout)

```
EthernetClient::setConnectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
EthernetClient::setTimeout(CONNECTION_INPUT_STREAMING_TIMEOUT);
```

(they help to shorten waiting times in case of timeout of the client connected to the EthernetServer)

More tips:

- when `EthernetServer::available()` returns `false` consider using `EthernetServer::flush()` to flush server buffers;
- when using `EthernetClient::write()` also use `EthernetClient::flush()` to ensure that all data has been sent;
- use `EthernetClient::close()` on dead/useless clients to free sockets easely.

Consider implementing a function to force-close network sockets, using the following code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <utility/w5100.h>
void closeAllSockets()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCK_NUM; i++)
     {
         SPI.beginTransaction(SPI_ETHERNET_SETTINGS);
         W5100.execCmdSn(i, Sock_CLOSE);
         SPI.endTransaction();
     }
}

void printAllSockets()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCK_NUM; i++)
     {
         Serial.print(F("Socket #"));
         Serial.print(i);
         uint8_ts = W5100.readSnSR(i);
         Serial.print(F(": 0x"));
         Serial.print(s, 16);
         Serial.print(F(" "));
         Serial.print(W5100.readSnPORT(i));
         Serial.print(F(" D:"));
         uint8_t dip[4];
         W5100.readSnDIPR(i, dip);
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
         {
             Serial.print(dip[j], 10);
             if (j < 3)
                 Serial.print(".");
         }
         Serial.print(F("("));
         Serial.print(W5100.readSnDPORT(i));
         Serial.println(F(")"));
     }
}
```

MAX_SOCK_NUM changes according to the network card, the Wiznet W5100 has a maximum of 4 sockets, the W5200 and W5500 has a maximum of 8 sockets.

Hope this helps someone.